# Quiuckboot in linux

Tags: boot

I am working on a project to reduce the boot up time & I find that U-boot loader takes much time to load so I want to directly boot from X loader so that my boot time get reduced.Is there any way to directly boot from X loader?

Answer (score 1):

You don't present a lot of information here. I assume you are working on an OMAP system? There is more information on the boot process here:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Boot_Sequence

There appear to be some memory constraints that require a small first stage loader. This site claims that x-loader is derived from U-boot and that both are needed:

http://omappedia.org/wiki/Bootloader_Project

I would suggest looking at streamlining your U-boot image. U-boot does filesystem discovery  and that may be the place where you are seeing the performance issues. It may significantly reduce your boot times if U-boot is looking at locations it does not really need to get the kernel and you can remove those checks. The kernel will also do filesystem interpretation.

Comment: how do i remove the checks & make the U-boot to look at precise location where kernel filesystem is available.